# Possible wrong ussage of transformPoint method from tf

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy, tf

ROS VERSION: Melodic
OS VERSION: Ubuntu 18.04
package tf version: 1.12.1

I'm trying to create a node that processes a PolygonStamped object and transform each point of it to a especified frame_id in order to calculate prohibited regions.

I'm publishing for this example the tf from utm to map as a traslation 5,5,0 (x,y,z) and no rotation.

Here is the fragment where I try to set up the transformation process:

```
        for zone in zones_dict:
            obj = PolygonStamped()
            obj.header.stamp = rospy.get_time()
            obj.header.frame_id = 'utm'
            obj.header.frame_id = zones_dict[zone]['frame_id']

            for point in zones_dict[zone]['points']:
                point_stamped = PointStamped()
                point_stamped.header.frame_id = str(zones_dict[zone]['frame_id'])
                point_stamped.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
                point_stamped.point.x = point[0]
                point_stamped.point.y = point[1]
                point_stamped.point.z = point[2]
                print(point_stamped)

                point_transformed = self.tf_listener.transformPoint(str(obj.header.frame_id), point_stamped)
            
                print(point_transformed)
                point_formatted = Point32()
                point_formatted.x = point_transformed.point.x
                point_formatted.y = point_transformed.point.y
                point_formatted.z = point_transformed.point.z

                obj.polygon.points.append(point_formatted)
```

Variable point_stamped

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1706527825
    nsecs:  68283081
  frame_id: "map"
point: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
```

Variable point_transformed

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1706527825
    nsecs:  68283081
  frame_id: "map"
point: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
```

Supposed behaviour (point_transformed)

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1706527825
    nsecs:  68283081
  frame_id: "utm"
point: 
  x: 5.0
  y: 5.0
  z: 0.0
```

Why the function transformPoint returns me the same point_stamped? Also I'm not aware of the state of tf2 in this version, since I have worked with Noetic, but should I use tf2 even in this outdated distribution of ROS?

Comment: Forgot to mention that if I try to debug the function just using "utm" instead of obj.header.frame_id on the transformPoint there's a lookUp exception. But the transformation is being published using static_transform_publisher and quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this issue attaching a waitForTransform function each time brefore using the transformPoint method. Perhaps it is related to tf trying to extrapolate the result.

But, despite that I think this is not the best way to do due to having multiple areas defined by a bunch of points would last longer than needed. If someone has some experience on this, any feedback is appreciated.